# Laravel many to many pivot table accessor

Tags: laravel, eloquent, fluent

I have a Users table and a Votes table and a vote_users table (many to many relationship)
In the vote_user table I have 
user_id|vote_id| anonymous.

How can I change the user_id to -1 (only when sending to client) , if anonymous column has value TRUE ?

Comment: because my application is not designed to work like that.
user and his votes need to be internally identifiable. that information should not reach the clients though

Comment: Well by changing the user_id to -1 you are essentially removing this identifier to the user.

Comment: I would suggest keeping the anonymous field then, don't reset the user_id, and when you query to show the user's votes (which is what I assume you're trying to do) make sure you are only taking votes where anonymous is false.

Comment: no, the application logic cannot be changed. I am specifically looking for mutating  as asked in my question. 
If I don't take the anonymous votes, the counts will be incorrect

Comment: What are you trying to hide and what are you trying to show? What is the purpose of setting the user_id to -1? If the purpose is for the view, meaning you want it say the user was anonymous when displaying the voting results then just make sure you check the anonymous value. I don't see why you are messing with the user_id if you do want to keep that information.

Comment: by 'setting' I mean when sending the array to the client. Not internally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114269/discussion-between-upful-and-harvey-slash).